# Is there any easy way to sort a JSONArray of objects by an attribute in Android?

Tags: android, json, sorting, arrays

Is there any easy way to sort a JSONArray of objects by an attribute in Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a JSONArray in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543862/how-can-i-sort-a-jsonarray-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using the Google GSON library you can deserialise the array to a typed collection of objects, and then using Collections perform a sort.

Look at 6th line in on the following link.. Looks a bit messy but might be quickest way..

http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

Comment: I was hoping to avoid deserializing into objects as the objects contain a lot of data and cost a lot to process.

Comment: Where is the JSON sourced from?

Comment: I get all the JSON via a webresponse string that I create a JSONArray from.

Comment: Can you not perform the sort on the server side then so the data is already in the order you require before pulling it to the device?