# How to sort GSON Array based on a key?

Tags: java, sorting, gson

Consider the following is my Array

```
[
  {"id":10,"name":"name10","valid":true},
  {"id":12,"name":"name12","valid":false},
  {"id":11,"name":"name11","valid":false},
  {"id":9,"name":"name9","valid":true}
]
```

Created a `JsonArray` out of it, like following code does:

```
//Create a JSON Parser using GSON library 
objJsonParser = new JsonParser();
String strArrayText = [{"id":9,"name":"name9","valid":true}, ...]
JsonArray jsonArrayOfJsonObjects = objJsonParser.parse(strArrayText).getAsJsonArray();
```

Now, I am trying to sort `jsonArrayOfJsonObjects` based on `name` field.

Desired Output:

```
[
  {"id":9,"name":"name9","valid":true},
  {"id":10,"name":"name10","valid":false},
  {"id":11,"name":"name11","valid":false},
  {"id":12,"name":"name12","valid":true}
]
```

Could anyone help to sort this out with best apporach with respect to Java & Gson?
Your inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to sort JSONArray of JSONObjects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901742/android-how-to-sort-jsonarray-of-jsonobjects)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)

Comment: @MattBall `JsonArray` is very specifically not a `Collection` to avoid having to do lots of object translations unnecessarily.

Comment: @chrylis sorting a list and then serializing it to JSON should produce the desired output, if I understand the question correctly. Perhaps the OP really just wants a sorted `JSONArray`, but I read it as asking for sorted JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the proper way to parse your JSON is to create a class to encapsulate your data, such as:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Boolean valid;
    //getters & setters
}
```

And then:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>() {}.getType();
List<MyClass> myList = new Gson().fromJson(strArrayText, listType);
```

---

Now you have a `List` and you want to sort it by the value of the attribute `id`, so you can use `Collections` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property):

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: You could also use an array and Java 8 lambdas: `MyClass[] objects = new Gson().fromJson(strArrayText, MyClass[].class); Arrays.sort(objects, (MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> m1.getId().compareTo(m2.getId()));`

Answer (score -1):

Try this library method as a simple **JSON-level alternative** to model classes creation:

```
/**
 * Sort JSON-array by a given key name (numbers or text expected).
 *
 * @param jsonArray     JSON-array to sort.
 * @param keyNameToSort Key name to sort by. Expected are integer type 
 *                      (sorted ascending) or string type (sorted 
 *                      alphabetically).
 */
public static JsonArray
sortJsonArrayByKey(
  JsonArray jsonArray,
  String keyNameToSort) {

  JsonArray sortedJsonArray = new JsonArray();
  JsonObject jsonObject = null;
  int jsonElementIndex;
  TreeMap<Integer, JsonObject> integerSortedObjects = new TreeMap<>();
  TreeMap<String, JsonObject> stringSortedObjects = new TreeMap<>();

  for (
    jsonElementIndex = 0;
    jsonElementIndex < jsonArray.size();
    jsonElementIndex++) {

    try {

      // A JSON-Object from JSON-array:

      jsonObject =
        jsonArray
          .get(
            jsonElementIndex)
          .getAsJsonObject();

    } catch (Exception notAnObject) {
    }

    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {

      // Look for the given key in the JSON-object:

      if (
        entry.getKey()
        .equals(keyNameToSort)) {

        try {

          // If key is of integer type:

          integerSortedObjects.put(
            entry
              .getValue()
              .getAsInt(),
            jsonObject);

        } catch (Exception notAnInt) {

          try {

            // If key is of string type:

            stringSortedObjects.put(
              entry
                .getValue()
                .getAsString(),
              jsonObject);

          } catch (Exception neitherIntNorString) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Add sorted by number values first:

  for (Integer key : integerSortedObjects.keySet()) {

    sortedJsonArray.add(
      integerSortedObjects.get(
        key));
  }

  // Add sorted by string values second:

  for (String key : stringSortedObjects.keySet()) {

    sortedJsonArray.add(
      stringSortedObjects.get(
        key));
  }

  return sortedJsonArray;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use Gson library https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide
to get the Array(the class should implement comparable) and sort with arrays.sort();

Thanks

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: You have the example in the answer, If I have to code it, the code would be same.