# Maintaining same order as JsonArray while de-serializing using gson

Tags: json, gson

I am not sure but it seems, when I de-serialize an object array using gson, the order is missed. For example, I have following json:

```
{   
    "Id": "b2340ca7-646b-44bd-8a35-8d3043ace98e", 
    "Arr2": [

        {
            "keyA1": "value1", 
            "keyA2": value2, 
            "keyA3": "value3"
        }, 
        {
            "keyB1": "value1", 
            "keyB2": value2, 
            "keyB3": "value3"
        }, 
        {
            "keyC1": "value1", 
            "keyC2": value2, 
            "keyC3": "value3"
        }
    ], 
    "key": "value", 
    "key": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": value2, 
        "key3": "value3"
    }, 
    "Arr1": [
        "Element 1", 
        "Element 2"
    ]
 }
```

After deserializing the order of elements in ARR2 is not same as in json above.

Comment: what do you mean by not the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)

Comment: Lets say I call first object in ARR2 as object A, 2nd object as Object B and 3rd as Object C. After I de-serialize this array Arr2 into a HashLinkedSet using gson, I expect the order of elements in set to be Object A, Object B, Object C. But instead I get Object C, Object A, Object B. How can I maintain the order of elements from jsonArray after deserialization.

Comment: This is not duplicate of [JSON order mixed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up) because that post talks about order of elements within json object. I need to maintain the order of objects after DE-SERIALIZATION of JSON ARRAY into linkedHashSet

Comment: It is a duplicate, it just talks about `java -> json`, which has the same lack of ordering specification as `json -> java'. My vote stands.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in your JSON serialization library, or possibly your code. The order of elements in an array is significant in JSON. What is *not* significant is the order of fields in an object.

Comment: @AustynMahoney It's not a duplicate, because http://www.json.org/ says:
> An array is an ordered collection of values

Comment: @user3175491 please post the classes you are deserializing to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort GSON Array based on a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575757/how-to-sort-gson-array-based-on-a-key)

Comment: did any one got the reason?