# Sorting an arraylist of jsonobjects on a particular json element

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I have written some code that creates an array list of json data using the Gson library which looks something like this.

```
{
 "filename": "somefile.mp3"
 "artist": "artist1"
 "title": "title1"
 "genre": "rock"
}
{
 "filename": "anotherfile.mp3"
 "artist": "artist2"
 "title": "title2"
 "genre": "electro"
}
```

Im trying to figure out how I can sort this array list by the artist element. Currently its just ordering it in the way it is created originally via the filename. Reading on stackoverflow suggests I should be trying to use a custom comparator. Ive been looking at this answer ([How to sort GSON Array based on a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575757/how-to-sort-gson-array-based-on-a-key)) but its not working for me.

I have a custom class called Tracks.class which has all the getters and setters set up holding title,artist,genre etc

TrackFileManager.class is the serializer and where all the JsonObject.addProperty code is and returns a jsonObject back to MainActivity.

this jsonObject then gets added to an ArrayList called values as below in MainActivity.
(listOfFiles is another array list that holds all the filenames of my mp3s)

```
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Track.class, new TrackFileManager());
gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
//diasableHtmlEscaping stops & turning into \u0026
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping().create();

values = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String file : listOfFiles){
    t = new Track(path,file);
    values.add(gson.toJson(t));
}
Collections.sort(values, new MyJSONComparator());
```

The other code i have is a MyJSONComparator.class which is below

```
public class MyJSONComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

This produces no errors but it doesnt sort it which I know it wont but its the only way for it not hint errors in Android Studio. If I change the code to `implements Comparator<Track>` the `Collections.sort` produces an error. And unless I have comparator I can't access the elements i want to sort on like `s1.getArtist` etc unless thats not the right way to do it?? I've also tried `ArrayList<String>` and pretty much all other combinations of types except the one that works.

Im obviously doing something wrong, im pretty sure im almost there.
Can anyone help or at least point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

```
public class MyJSONComparator implements Comparator<Track> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Track s1, Track s2) {
        return s1.artist.compareTo(s2.artist);
    }
}
```

The above code causes `Collections.sort(values,new MyJSONComparator());` to error.

`Sort (List<String>, java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.string> in Collections cannot be applied to ArrayList<String>, com.example.MyJSONComparator.`

Answer (score 0):

Your compare function should take the objects as input

```
@Override
public int compare(Object s1, Object s2) {
    return s1.artist.compareTo(s2.artist);
}
```

Collection.sort will work on the list ,having objects implementing the same comparator interface.

refer the below link
http://www.programcreek.com/2011/12/examples-to-demonstrate-comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/

Comment: Which is the pojo class for the below object ??
{
 "filename": "somefile.mp3"
 "artist": "artist1"
 "title": "title1"
 "genre": "rock"
}

TrackFileManager ? ....if yes then this should in your list and this is the class which should implement Comparator

Comment: Its an arraylist of Gson created JsonObjects based on the Tracks class. So POJO is Tracks. TrackFileManager is the serializer that creates the json.

Answer (score 0):

What a difference a good night sleep makes.
Im not sure why I thought I needed to use Json's in the program. I obviously dont.
In the program Im creating a list of Tracks then converting them to json strings, then trying to sort the json on one of its elements. Why not just sort the tracks class on one of its elements instead.

Derp.

This now sits in the Track class and is triggered by `Collections.sort(tracks)`. The instance of the track is built via another method using setters which is just like the .addproperty stuff I was doing in the Gson related code.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Track t) {
    return this.artist.compareTo(t.artist);
}
```