# How to create json, sorted on keys, using gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to create constant json string or a json sorted on keys. What do I mean by constant json string? Please look into following code sample, which I created.

**My Code 1:**

```
public class GsonTest
{
    class DataObject {

        private int data1 = 100;
        private String data2 = "hello";

    }   


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GsonTest obj=new GsonTest();
        DataObject obj2 = obj.new DataObject();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = gson.toJson(obj2);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

**Output 1:**

```
{"data1":100,"data2":"hello"}
```

**My Code 2:**

```
public class GsonTest
{
    class DataObject {
        private String data2 = "hello";
        private int data1 = 100;


    }   


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GsonTest obj=new GsonTest();
        DataObject obj2 = obj.new DataObject();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = gson.toJson(obj2);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

**Output 2:**

```
{"data2":"hello","data1":100}
```

If you see, if I switch variables (`data1` & `data2` in `DataObject` class), I get different json. My objective to get same json, even if somebody changes position of the class variables. I get it when somebody adds new variables, json would change. But json shouldn't change when variables are moved around. So, my objective is to get standard json, possibly in sorted keys order for same class. If there is nested json, then it should be sorted in the nested structure.

**Expected output on run of both the codes**:

```
{"data1":100,"data2":"hello"}  //sorted on keys!! Here keys are data1 & data2
```

I understand, I need to change something in `String json = gson.toJson(obj2);` line, but what do I have to do?

**Why I need them to be order?**

I need to encode the json string and then pass it to another function. If I change the order of keys, even though value remain intact, the encoded value will change. I want to avoid that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515863/669721

Comment: fwiw, in json, the keys are unordered.  So, building something else that relies on any particular ordering is a questionable idea... unless you want this just for aesthetics.

Comment: @FatalError I want them to be in order because I'll be encoding of the json string. If keys moved around, my encoding will change and I don't want to do that. Edited in question as well. So, I would need it to be sorted.

Comment: @Miroshko link doesn't address my problem completely. Here the problem is class structure can change.

Comment: @Abhishek: Imo you'd be better served to deserialize the json and then hash the resulting object in some normalized way where you have control over exactly what you're hashing.  The same object could be serialized many equivalent ways into a JSON object -- even if the fields are in the same order, it could have extra whitespace (e.g. pretty printed) etc.

Comment: @FatalError I'm not doing pretty printed or any other formatting stuff. So, I don't think that would be an issue here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort GSON Array based on a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575757/how-to-sort-gson-array-based-on-a-key)

Answer (score 13):

First of all, the keys of a json object are **unordered** by definition, see http://json.org/.

If you merely want a json string with ordered keys, you can try deserializing your json into a sorted map, and then serialize the map in order to get the sorted-by-key json string.

```
GsonTest obj=new GsonTest();
DataObject obj2 = new DataObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(obj2);
TreeMap<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, TreeMap.class);
String sortedJson = gson.toJson(map);
```

Comment: This partially answers my question. Why partially? It is because when I tried nested json, it didn't gave me expected output in nested structure.

Comment: @Abhishek Well, if you want to sort nested structure as well, maybe json object(map) is not the perfect choice of representation, as already discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515676/keep-the-order-of-the-json-keys-during-json-conversion-to-csv/4515863#4515863

Comment: @Abhishek However, if you could show me a simple use case, maybe I'm able to help you.

Comment: simple use case if that I need to calculate difference of huge json files. The keys needn't follow same order in both jsons, that is the issue. I thought of comparing encoded values instead of comparing json string.

Comment: Beware that this trick will also rewrite your numbers into double, for example `{ "key":1 }` gets rewritten as `{ "key":1.0 }`.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have mentioned that by design JSON is not supposed to have sorted keys in itself. You can also come up with a recursive solution to do it. I won't say my solution is very efficient but it does the intended job. Please have a look at the following piece of code.

```
private static JsonObject sortAndGet(JsonObject jsonObject) {
    List<String> keySet = jsonObject.keySet().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    JsonObject temp = new JsonObject();
    for (String key : keySet) {
        JsonElement ele = jsonObject.get(key);
        if (ele.isJsonObject()) {
            ele = sortAndGet(ele.getAsJsonObject());
            temp.add(key, ele);
        } else if (ele.isJsonArray()) {
            temp.add(key, ele.getAsJsonArray());
        } else
            temp.add(key, ele.getAsJsonPrimitive());
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Input:

```
{"c":"dhoni","a":"mahendra","b":"singh","d":{"c":"tendulkar","b":"ramesh","a":"sachin"}}
```

Output:

```
{"a":"mahendra","b":"singh","c":"dhoni","d":{"a":"sachin","b":"ramesh","c":"tendulkar"}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps a work around is for your class wrap a TreeMap which maintains sort order of the keys.  You can add getters and setters for convenience. When you gson the TreeMap, you'll get ordered keys.