# Arrange the array depending on the order android?

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I have a webservice and I get this response when I call the webservice.

```
[
    {
        "ProjectID": 1,
        "SLNO": 1,
        "ID": 1,
        "Type": "Text",
        "Name": "First Name",
        "**Order**": 1,
        "Flag": "F"
    },
    {
        "ProjectID": 1,
        "SLNO": 3,
        "ID": 2,
        "Type": "Text",
        "Name": "Company",
        "**Order**": 5,
        "Flag": "F"
    },
    {
        "ProjectID": 1,
        "SLNO": 4,
        "ID": 4,
        "Type": "Text",
        "Name": "Personal Email",
        "**Order**": 3,
        "Flag": "F"
    },
    {
        "ProjectID": 1,
        "SLNO": 2,
        "ID": 8,
        "Type": "Text",
        "Name": "Last Name",
        "**Order**": 2,
        "Flag": "F"
    }
]
```

Now I want to sort this complete  array depending on the order which I get inside this array? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have parsed the json and got the values of Name and Order.

Comment: you can take a look at this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901742/android-how-to-sort-jsonarray-of-jsonobjects

Comment: If you use your own API then try to sort array server side using OREDER BY query and if not then do it in Android side with array sorting function...

Comment: Can you please explain How can I do this in android side?

Answer (score 1):

```
array = JSONUtil.sort(array, new Comparator(){
               public int compare(Object a, Object b){
                  JSONObject    ja = (JSONObject)a;
                  JSONObject    jb = (JSONObject)b;
                  return Integer.valueOf(ja.getString("**Order**")).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(jb.getString("**Order**")));
               }
            });
```

Comment: what will come under object1 and object2?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add these data in list like an ArrayList or HashMap. Then use the below code to sort your list data based on order.

```
class HashMapComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> {
        private final String key;

        public HashMapComparator(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs,
                HashMap<String, String> rhs) {
            String firstValue = lhs.get(key);
            String secondValue = rhs.get(key);
            return firstValue.compareTo(secondValue);
        }
    }
```

and call it as:

```
 Collections.sort(yourlistDTO, new HashMapComparator("order"));
```

Comment: It is showing me classcast exception on Collections.sort() method

Comment: what parameter you are passing ?

Comment: I have added the json array in arraylist. and then called this fuction.

Comment: JSONArray  jsonArray;
   
   try {
    jsonArray= new JSONArray(result);
   // Log.e("ARRAY IS", jsonArray.toString());
    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){ 
        listdata.add(jsonArray.toString());
       } 
    Log.e("LIST IS", listdata.toString());
    Collections.sort(listdata, new HashMapComparator("Order"));

Comment: this is wrong way, by this way you are saving whole jason string in arrayList element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45629/discussion-between-user2699728-and-jay)

Comment: your json array will not get sorted, list will sorted.