# Android get data from json and sort

Tags: java, android, json

- I'm trying to get data from json. I can get data at first state.
- But how to get data "ascending" and "descending" and show it on another activity in listview ?

**Here's My Json**

```
[{"category_name":"Food","filter_type":"Sort by","field_name":"","type":"VALUE","table_name":"","item_list":["Ascending","Descending"]}
```

**And here's my Java code**

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
    try {

        foods = new JSONArray(jsonStr);


        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < foods.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = foods.getJSONObject(i);

            if(c.getString("category_name").equals("Food")) {

                String category_name = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY_NAME);
                String table_name = c.getString(TAG_TABLE_NAME);
                String item_list = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_LIST);

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(TAG_CATEGORY_NAME, category_name);
                contact.put(TAG_TABLE_NAME, table_name);
                contact.put(TAG_ITEM_LIST, item_list);

                // adding contact to contact list
                foodlistfilter.add(contact);

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
}
```

I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/, but i still don't fully understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain this.

[ means its an array.
{ is an object.

In your case it's an array whcih contains an -JSONObject with name category_name, filter_type and field_name. type and table_name and a new jsonarray with object item_list.

How can you parse this string?

Here is an example:

```
String str = "[{"category_name":"Food","filter_type":"Sort by","field_name":"","type":"VALUE","table_name":"","item_list":["Ascending","Descending"]}";

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
//now it holds the JSONObject.
for (int i = 0; i<= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
 //now we loop through and get the jsonObject
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i));
 //now it contains your data.
 Log.d("Category_nameValue=", jsonObj.getString("category_name"));
 //now we want to get the array from the item_list. 
 JSONArray itemList = new JSONArray(jsonObj.getString("item_list")); 
 //now itemList.getString(1);  === Ascending while itemList.getString(2) == Descending



 //now itemList contains several new objects which can also be looped as the parent one.
}
```

Since you now know how to create an JSONArray, you can start sorting it.

This has been answered already at [Android how to sort JSONArray of JSONObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901742/android-how-to-sort-jsonarray-of-jsonobjects)

If you want to send those data to another Activity you can use the JSONArray.toString() method and send it via Intents.

This is easy explained at [Pass a String from one Activity to another Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/how-to-pass-string-one-activity-to-another)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But what I mean is not sorting the data. If you see the item_list, there're two data ( Ascending and Descending ) inside the array.
What I want is get that data, and show it on another activity in listview.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D. Now What I have to do is just make a list from an intent, right.

Answer (score 1):

To get a `JSONArray` from your `JSONObject c`
simply write:

```
JSONArray itemList = c.getJSONArray(name);
```

then you can iterate through that data like any other array

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.length(); i++) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are (sometimes) good, but code+explanation answers are (most times) better

Answer (score 1):

If you're new, I would recommend you think about using Gson to parse your Json response directly to a java entity class. So you will avoid to manually parse all your responses.

**Your JSON response**

```json
[{"category_name":"Food","filter_type":"Sort by","field_name":"","type":"VALUE","table_name":"","item_list":["Ascending","Descending"]}
```

**The entity representing the response**

```java
public class MyEntity {
    String category_name;
    String filter_type;
    String field_name;
    String type;
    String table_name;
    String [] item_list;

   // getters / setters ...
}
```

**Parsing the response**

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyEntity myEntity = gson.fromJson(response, MyEntity.class);
```

Finally, to **send the data**, start the new Activity with extras

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", myEntity.getCategoryName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Now you **recover the extra** data on your AnotherActivity

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
String categoryName = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_DATA");
```

And you can **fill the ListView** using an ArrayAdapter: [Example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample)