# How can I sort a JSONArray in JAVA

Tags: java, json, sorting

How to sort a JSONArray of objects by object's field?

Input:

```
[
    { "ID": "135", "Name": "Fargo Chan" },
    { "ID": "432", "Name": "Aaron Luke" },
    { "ID": "252", "Name": "Dilip Singh" }
];
```

Desired output (sorted by "Name" field):

```
[
    { "ID": "432", "Name": "Aaron Luke" },
    { "ID": "252", "Name": "Dilip Singh" }
    { "ID": "135", "Name": "Fargo Chan" },
];
```

Comment: I want the sorting on the basis of "Name". Output should be:
432 Aaron Luke
252 Dilip Singh
135 Fargo Chan

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try this:

```
    //I assume that we need to create a JSONArray object from the following string
    String jsonArrStr = "[ { \"ID\": \"135\", \"Name\": \"Fargo Chan\" },{ \"ID\": \"432\", \"Name\": \"Aaron Luke\" },{ \"ID\": \"252\", \"Name\": \"Dilip Singh\" }]";

    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonArrStr);
    JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();

    List<JSONObject> jsonValues = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        jsonValues.add(jsonArr.getJSONObject(i));
    }
    Collections.sort( jsonValues, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
        //You can change "Name" with "ID" if you want to sort by ID
        private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";

        @Override
        public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
            String valA = new String();
            String valB = new String();

            try {
                valA = (String) a.get(KEY_NAME);
                valB = (String) b.get(KEY_NAME);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
                //do something
            }

            return valA.compareTo(valB);
            //if you want to change the sort order, simply use the following:
            //return -valA.compareTo(valB);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        sortedJsonArray.put(jsonValues.get(i));
    }
```

The sorted JSONArray is now stored in the `sortedJsonArray` object.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Helped alot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not need the for loop at the end.

Comment: I know this works but it is terrible that we have to resort to something like this to reuse the sort function knowing that JsonArray contains the items as a collection `private final List<JsonElement> elements`, but private !

Comment: good answer but this will not ignore case (A>B>C>a)

Comment: forgot to add for future me and others - just change it to `compareToIgnoreCase`

Comment: this helps me a lot, thanks

Comment: What if I have to sort based on a nested key? Like below

 [
    {
      "identifier": {
        "id": "123bsdd123",
        "name": "JAMES",
        "category": "GOLD"
      }
    },
    {
      "identifier": {
        "id": "3334sfdfs12",
        "name": "JAMES",
        "category": "GOLD"
      }
    }
 ]

I want to sort based on id. How do I implement that?

Comment: Leaving this here just in case somebody needs this in Kotlin: https://gist.github.com/ArnyminerZ/6aca0630a96f5559d3b9b797c9b48f3f

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!