# Java - sort JSONArray based on two attribute values

Tags: java, arrays, json, comparator

I have a JSONArray as below,

```
JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray();
dataArray = [
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "row": 1,
        "value": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "row": 1,
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "name3",
        "row": 2,
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "name4",
        "row": 3,
        "value": 30
    },
    {
        "name": "name5",
        "row": 3,
        "value": 10
    }
]
```

I need to compare the `row` attribute, if same, need to compare `value` attribute and sort the object in the array.

Tried with Java comparator, but couldn't make it work. Can somebody please help?

```
            
   for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.size(); i++) {
       elementList.add((JSONObject) dataArray.get(i));
   }
   Long row1 = null;
   for (JSONObject obj : elementList) {
       if(row1 == null) {
           row1 = (Long) ((JSONObject) obj.get("row"));
       }
       else {
            Long row2 = (Long) ((JSONObject) obj.get("row"));
            if(row2 == row1) {
                //call the comparator, but how to pass two objects?
            }
            row1 = row2;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Your code is not valid Java, can you show some example code that compiles and runs?

Comment: *"Tried with Java comparator, but couldn't make it work."* please [edit] your question to include your attempt, so we can start from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It  would be easy to extend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546513/7237884) to match your scenario

But instead of

```
 return valA.compareTo(valB);
```

you should do

```
     int comp = valA.compareTo(valB);
        if (comp == 0){
            String valC = (String) a.get(KEY_NAME2);
            String valD = (String) b.get(KEY_NAME2);
            return valC.compareTo(valD);
        } else {
            return comp;
        }
```

So it should be the following.

```
    JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    List<JSONObject> jsonValues = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {   // <---- dataArray is the input that you have
        jsonValues.add(dataArray.getJSONObject(i));
    }
    Collections.sort( jsonValues, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
        //You can change "Name" with "ID" if you want to sort by ID
        private static final String KEY_NAME1 = "row";
        private static final String KEY_NAME2 = "value";

        @Override
        public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
            String valA = new String();
            String valB = new String();

            try {
                valA = (String) a.get(KEY_NAME1);
                valB = (String) b.get(KEY_NAME1);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                //do something
            }

            int comp = valA.compareTo(valB);
            if (comp == 0){
                String valC = (String) a.get(KEY_NAME2);
                String valD = (String) b.get(KEY_NAME2);
                return valC.compareTo(valD);
            } else {
                return comp;
            }
        }
    });
```

**Edit**: changed into `KEY_NAME1 = "row";` to match the new question requirement

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I had to change `String` to `Integer` and `Long`. I see the Objects sorted now!!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach here:

You could convert your JSON string to `List<YourObject>` by using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`

```java
List<YourObject> list = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<YourObject>>(){});
```

Then use `Collections.sort`  and `Comparator` to sort this list. You can also implement a custom `Comparator` to sort a list by multiple attributes depending on your situation.

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getRow)
    .thenComparing(YourObject::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you deserialize your json data into objects like

```java
public class DataRow {
    private String name;
    private int row;
    private int value;
    // Getter, Setter, Constructor what ever needed
}
```

Then you can work with a list and stream like:

```java
List<DataRow> datarows = //... read data from json

List<DataRow> sorted = datarows.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(DataRow::getRow).thenComparingInt(DataRow::getValue)).toList();
```